# php Sessions on Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

There is VK-app:

1. https://vk.com/mafia_forumgame

and the domain URL

2. https://vk.frontprint.ru/test2.php

They point to this script:

```
<?php
    session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) $_SESSION['counter']=0;

echo "You refresh page ".$_SESSION['counter']++." times.
     <br> <a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].">refresh</a>
     Tech info:".session_id()." at ".session_save_path();
?>
```

Everywhere work fine, except Chrome when i open p.1

Every refresh page **https://vk.com/mafia_forumgame** in Chrome create new session on server.

But page **https://vk.frontprint.ru/test2.php** works, updating the counter.